# How to handle Nones in CSV when reading it into a struct?

Tags: c++

I'm reading a CSV file into a struct in C++. Sometimes entries, for example of the column `age`, are not available and are replaced by `None`. How do I correctly handle `None`. I would like to replace them by -1 to show, that the data was not available. Currently I am doing the following

```
std::string tmp;
std::getline(string_stream, tmp, ',');
try {
    data.age = std::stoi(tmp);
}
catch (std::exception& e){
    data.age = -1.0;
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do that? My file consists of many columns and checking if the data exists makes the code much longer.

Comment: The `data.age = xxx` smells like you are copypasting the above code for each data column. To make this more "elegant", the first thing to do is to factor it out into a separate function.

Answer (score 0):

```
data.age = isdigit(tmp.at(0)) ? std::stoi(tmp) : -1;
```

Comment: What about the following strings: "-2", "+2", "" or "6sigma"?

Comment: @HAL9000 do you know a person who has `-2` age old ?! Me no

Comment: Who said anything about persons?

Comment: @HAL9000 I did not see in the question that age in the CSV is a signed value. if it does not exist, it is equal to `NONE` string

Comment: My point is that you are making assumptions of the inputs, and not checking if the input is valid. Sometimes that is all you want. But if your code is not "generic" you should write so in your answer.